# How to find JavaScript functions in a JavaScript (.js) file command line?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a way to get all the top level functions, properties and methods defined in a `.js` file without a browser, preferably in command line. I have looked into [esprima](http://esprima.org/) parser and [escope](https://github.com/Constellation/escope) but it seems to be an overkill really.

I've seen other questions here asking similar questions, but I'm looking for a solution not using a browser(without the `window` object), using something like `rhino` javascript engine.

Is there a simple way to achieve this without using a javascript parser?

Comment: Rhino contains, and depends on, a JavaScript parser: how else could a JavaScript engine work? It might help if you could explain why parsing the JavaScript seems like "overkill" to you.

Comment: No, you cannot avoid a javascript parser. It depends however on your whether a static analysis will be enough, whether you need to interpret the file or if you even will need to simulate an environment. Think of a polyfill that conditionall exports functions.

Comment: @ruakh - by overkill I mean to use esprima to produce a SAT tree, and traverse it just to get all global function names. Im guessing someone who knows JavaScript well could do this in 10 lines of code.. but I could be wrong since I dont know much about JavaScript.

Comment: @Bergi - I just need a static analysis of a `js` file. I realize this may not be enough to get all the function names in all cases.

Comment: Using a parser alone is overkill, so let's use a whole execution engine?

Comment: @WeaselFox: For that, we would at least need to know the structure of your code - assuming it's equally structured. Can you post some example?